# Can't find path when using JAR file

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, jar

I am trying to store a file in a specific folder. If I run the programm through Intelli J using arguments it works completelly fine and the file is created in the desired folder. But it I run the programm through the command line (JAR file) I get a file not found exception(the system couldn't find the specified path).

I think this happens because the path from the JAR file to the folder where I want to store the file is different from the path from my Main class to the folder.

How can I solve this problem?

### File generating method

```
 public void generateMigrationFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        Document migrationDocument=new Document();

        Namespace namespace = Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog");
        Element databaseChangelogElement = new Element("databaseChangeLog", namespace);
        Namespace XSI = Namespace.getNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        databaseChangelogElement.addNamespaceDeclaration(XSI);
        databaseChangelogElement.setAttribute("schemaLocation", "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd", XSI);

        Element changeSetElement=new Element("changeSet",namespace);
        changeSetElement.setAttribute("author","");
        changeSetElement.setAttribute("id",UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        databaseChangelogElement.addContent(changeSetElement);

        migrationDocument.setRootElement(databaseChangelogElement);
        
        XMLOutputter outter=new XMLOutputter();
        outter.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
        outter.output(migrationDocument, new FileWriter(new File("src\\main\\resources\\db\\changelog\\"+fileName+".xml")));

        System.out.println("Migration file generated successfully");
    }
```

### Project structure

[image: Project structure]

Comment: You look like you're trying to save a file as a _resource_. Resources should be considered read-only. And `src/main/resources/db/changelog/...` is a relative path that gets resolved against the working directory.

Comment: It can't be read-only. It generates a template to a migration that should be filled

Comment: Well, resources are read-only. There is no API for writing to resources. Ultimately your code is trying to write to a file "next to" the JAR file, not "in" the JAR file. But the `src/main/resources/db/changelog` directory doesn't exist unless your working directory is the project directory. You can of course create that directory in whatever the working directory is, but your user may not appreciate that.

Comment: What do you do with this file anyway? Is it only used by your program? Or does the user need to interact with it?

Comment: This file is a template of a liquibase migration. It must be filled

Comment: Then why not create only the file in the working directory? Or let the user specify where they want the file to be generated? If the user needs to manually fill the file then they should control where it's generated so they can easily find it.

Comment: In order to run the migration when the application is run the file must be in the folder db.changelog(liquibase requires it)

Comment: Then I can think of two options. (1) Create the `db/changelog` directory first (see `File#mkdirs()` or `Files#createDirectories(Path)`) then create the file. This will all be relative to the _working directory_ (which is not necessarily the same directory that the JAR file is in). (2) Create the XML file in the working directory (or let the user specify location), let the user manually fill it, then have your program copy it into a (temporary) directory with the correct path and then perform the migration.

Comment: Is it possible to alter a variable value of a jar file? For example if I have a variable with the  value 100 and have a method that sums 100 to that variable. If I compile the programm to a jar file and run that method the variable updates it's value?

Answer (score 1):

If you ar running a jar, there is no `src/main` directory.
everything in this directory will be put into the jar while maven build it.

use an absolute path or write into a temporary directory, or make the directory configurable

Comment: But my absolute path is different from other's person absolute path

Comment: How would the temporary directory approach work?

Comment: https://javatutorialhq.com/java/example-source-code/io/file/check-temp-directory-java/#:~:text=The%20temp%20directory%20is%20where%20the%20files%20would,source%20code%20differs%20depending%20on%20your%20machine%20settings.

Comment: In order to make the migrations work they must be in the folder where I am storing them(that's how liquibase works)

Comment: But you can't store into a directory which is not existent